# Java: embedding jar inside exe

Tags: java, exe

Here is example to show what i mean: http://www.minecraft.net/download.jsp
If you open the Minecraft.exe with winrar you can see the jar manifest and classes and you can actually launch the jar like this `java -jar Minecraft.exe`

But when i tried to embed my jar to my own exe as resource (i can see the classes same way as in minecraft.exe with winrar) and launch it with java -jar it fails with message

```
invalid or corrupt jar file
```

How can i embed the jar to exe correctly? so it can be launched same way as minecraft.exe?

Comment: If you can open the exe with winrar, then it's not really an exe.  What's in the manifest?  Is there a Main-class there?

Comment: @Nick There is main class and manifest, but i dont know how minecraft packs the classes to exe so that java can use that exe like jar. You can even add that minecraft.exe to classpath and java is able to see the classes.

Comment: @sidd: as far as I remember the `.exe` format requires some signature bytes at the beginning and allows "random crap" at the end. The ZIP format (on which jar is based) requires some signature bytes near the end and allows "random crap" in front of its content. The combination of the two means that you have a file that is both a valid .exe and a valid .zip/.jar.

Comment: You mean theres a Main-Class specified in the manifest?  That's how the java -jar command works (http://bit.ly/9uNJgs).

Comment: @Joachim that's an interesting trick but how would the prefix bytes cause the JVM to run?

Comment: @Joachim that is exactly what i need, do you have any examples?

Comment: @sidd: the tools mentioned below do exactly that.

Comment: @NickHolt sure it can be.  Zips (and hence jars) read from the end of the file, EXE's from the front.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSmooth. We use it with much success

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [Jar2Exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/).  I don't know if it's the same tool that Minecraft uses however.

Answer (score 0):

[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) is another tool that supports this (with quite a few extra features such as auto-downloading a JRE if necessary).