# Using java, cmd and batch files

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, minecraft

I am pretty much a java noob, but I am fair in javascript and other web based coding languages. I read a few chapters of a book on java a year ago, and only wrote a few basic programs.
That said, I am better than I ought to be at filling in the gaps using other knowledge. Essentially, I have learned how to write batch files and use java in them by trial and error, over the last few hours. 
My problem is as follows. I have both 64 and 32 bit JRE installed on my computer, but I want to open minecraft with 32 bit (it defaults to 64).
Yes, seems easy. Write a good old batch that looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
java -d32 -jar Minecraft.exe
PAUSE
```

I save this as run.bat and keep it in a folder with Minecraft.exe, however when I open it, It says it cannot open the jarfile Minecraft.exe. I am fully aware that .exe is not a jarfile but I have seen almost identical code used for allocating more memory to a server, which worked with

```
-jar minecraft_server.exe
```

Why does it work there? And how can I fix my problem?

Further information: "java" works as an operation in cmd, and the PATH variable leads to 32 bit anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: `minecraft_server.exe` is a jar file, believe it or not. It's both a jar file and an exe file.

Comment: That's fantastic news and terible news. Why then does the code not have access to the .exe file?

Comment: By altering the path variable, I can flick between 32 and 64 bit java on my computer with ease. Minecraft, however, won't open with 32 bit, even when the path is set there, and even if I delete 64 bit Java! That said, it is fully capable of running on 32 bit.

Comment: @immibis Apparently it depends how you build the exe file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913120/java-embedding-jar-inside-exe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who read the question or were about to answer, and to immibis for the helpful comment. I have resolved the issue after some time.
By reassigning the PATH variable, (delete and replace), then changing my batch file to read

```
@ECHO OFF
java -d32 -jar Minecraft.exe
PAUSE
```

It removed the need to change the directory with the

```
cd "...path..."
```

code.
This resolved the issue.